# Passing textbox value to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a Js function in my asp.net page like this:

```
 function LoginPopup(username,password) {     

        alert(username);
        alert(password);

        username = username.val();
        password = password.val();

}
```

and I am using it like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="LoginPopup('<%# UsernameTextBox.ClientID %>', '<%# PasswordTextBox.ClientID %>');  return false;"
                                    CssClass="login-button" Text="<%$ Resources: HRGELoggedOutMaster, Login %>">
                                </asp:Button>
```

but I see that LoginPopup gets "<%# UsernameTextBox.ClientID %>" instead of UsernameTextBox's client Id. I want to pass UsernameTextBox and PasswordTextBox values to LoginPoup.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is the fields are used in inside of gridview?

Comment: no, it is is not in gridview

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, `document.getElementById()`

```
function LoginPopup(username,password) {    
    alert(username);
    alert(password);
    username = document.getElementById(username).value;
    password = document.getElementById(password).value;
}
```

Comment: how to call LoginPopup ?

Comment: OnClientClick="LoginPopup('<%# UsernameTextBox.ClientID %>', '<%# PasswordTextBox.ClientID %>');  return false;"

Comment: It shows this html: <input type="button" name="ctl00$ctl00$RegisterantSignup1$btnLogin" value="LOGIN" onclick="LoginPopup('&lt;%=UsernameTextBox.ClientID %&gt;', '&lt;%=PasswordTextBox.ClientID %&gt;');  return false;__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$RegisterantSignup1$btnLogin','')" id="ctl00_ctl00_RegisterantSignup1_btnLogin" class="login-button">

Answer (score 0):

Corrected the `ClientID` syntax:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="LoginPopup('<%=UsernameTextBox.ClientID %>', '<%=PasswordTextBox.ClientID %>');  return false;"
                                CssClass="login-button" Text="<%$ Resources: HRGELoggedOutMaster, Login %>">
                            </asp:Button>
```

If this is not working, you can try this way, you are not using the button on server side anyway:

```
    <input type="button" onclick="LoginPopup('<%=UsernameTextBox.ClientID %>', <%=PasswordTextBox.ClientID %>')" />
```

And in js (I assume you use jQuery):

```
 function LoginPopup(username,password) {  
    username = $('#' + username).val();
    password = $('#' + password).val();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @DotnetSparrow This is the correct syntax. You know that in order to work this has to be placed in the one and only form with `runat="Server"`?

Comment: yes that is the case, there is only one form with runat server

Comment: If you look at the source code of the button in the browser, there are the clientIds, or the `<%=...%>`? Maybe there is some other problem with Asp.Net.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow If you use Asp.Net 4+, you can ask it to not change the id using this: `ClientIDMode="Static"`.

Comment: there are two controls with usernametextbox name, one one page and other on master page.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Gridview then try this sample way

```
<ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkgettext" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("return callme({0})", (((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("txtName") as TextBox).ClientID) %>'
                        Text="Gettextboxvalue"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and javascript function to test is -

```
function callme(cntrl) {
            alert(cntrl.id);
            alert(cntrl.value);
            return false;
}
```